# iPhone doesn't display 'via App Name' for photos uploaded

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We are using the Facebook iOS SDK to upload photos from our iPhone application, here are the details:

1. App is approved in the App Center, including namespace, app id, deep linking, etc...
2. App is approved in iTunes
3. User provides permissions to publish on their behalf
4. We use the startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" to post the the users album and news feed

Now our issue:

For the post on Facebook Application on iPads, we get the desired behavior of 'via App Name' with a the App Name being linked to the application or redirecting correctly to the iTunes store.

On iPhones, we have tested 4 & 5 versions, we don't get the 'via App Name' with the post.  We have tried several things, verified settings in the App entries, but aren't able to resolve this.  Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Please share if u get a solution